# Setting a custom root URL in Play 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a play appliaction that works if It is the root of the web host however I want to load it as a sub-url of my host

That is

```
http://example.com/ <- This works fine and i want to move to it 
http://example.com/AwesomePlayApplication/  <- This want me to rewrite all the routes
```

Is there a way to just set a custom root URL that will translate all my configured routes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following configuration key in your `conf/application.conf` file:

```
application.context="/AwesomePlayApplication"
```

Comment: in play 2.5.x this is now play.http.context="/AwesomePlayApplication"

Comment: When I tried putting that into conf/application.conf, it did not work. I had to start the server with -Dplay.http.context="/AwesomePlayApplication

Answer (score 7):

As stated by James Roper on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/FfM_BA7HsbM/xMnTppxOGHoJ) : `Play 2.0.*` does not support running on a different context yet, but `Play 2.1` will.